# How to expose a Java interface type through jax-rs

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am using the Jersey implementation of jax-rs. I have a domain object that gets returned by a REST resource. It looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3711391025272861884L;

private IInterface config;

@XmlElement
public IInterface getConfig() {
    return config;
}
}
```

Where IInterface is a Java interface type.

Jax-ws says bombs out, saying:
Accessor null of SomeObject: An interface type cannot be an xml type. -> [Help 1]

I've googled around and haven't figured out how to do this. How can I tell Jax-ws how to deal with this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map fields/properties that are of an interface type by using the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify a concrete impl type:

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3711391025272861884L;

    private IInterface config;

    @XmlElement(type=IInterfaceImpl.class)
    public IInterface getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Amazingly helpful thanks! It is unfortunate my search did not lead to that post.